# Swift: Different number of cells in a row of a UICollectionView iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I want to mix the layout flow of a UICollectionView to both vertical and horizontal, i want to have every row divisible by 2 to have a single item, else it should have a two column grid, i have exhausted every approach i can think of, i end of getting one item per row.

**The image below is exactly what i want to achieve.**

[image]

**This is what i tried**

```
    class TrendVC: UIViewController {

    fileprivate let itemsPerRow: CGFloat = 2

    fileprivate let sectionInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    var data = [ "others", "sports", "kitchen", "phones", "entertainment", "electronics", "women"]
    var dataNames = ["Bags", "Sports & Outdoor", "Kitchen Essentials", "Mobile Phones & Tablets", "Entertainment", "Audio and Video", "Women's Clothings"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.backgroundColor = .white

                navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
                navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: UIBarMetrics.default)
                navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()

        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.delegate = self

        collectionView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)

    }


}

extension TrendVC: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout{

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return data.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        if indexPath.item % 3 == 0{

            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "DoubleCell", for: indexPath) as! DoubleTrendCellCell

            let datum = data[indexPath.item]

            let dat = dataNames[indexPath.item]

            cell.trendNameLabel.text = dat

            cell.trendImageView.image = UIImage(named: datum)

            return cell
        }else{
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "TrendCell", for: indexPath) as! SingleTrendCell

            let datum = data[indexPath.item]

            let dat = dataNames[indexPath.item]

            cell.trendNameLabel.text = dat

            cell.trendImageView.image = UIImage(named: datum)

            return cell
        }
    }


    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

        if indexPath.item % 3 == 0{
            let paddingSpace = sectionInsets.left * (2 + 1)
            let availableWidth = view.frame.width - paddingSpace
            let widthPerItem = availableWidth / itemsPerRow

            return CGSize(width: widthPerItem, height: widthPerItem)
        }
        let paddingSpace = sectionInsets.left * (2 + 1)
        let availableWidth = view.frame.width - paddingSpace
        let widthPerItem = availableWidth / itemsPerRow
        return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: widthPerItem)

    }

    //3
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                        layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                        insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
        return sectionInsets
    }

    // 4
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                        layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                        minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return sectionInsets.left
    }
}
```

This is what i am getting

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to calculate modulo with `3` instead of `2` to get the desired output.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    if indexPath.item % 3 == 0{
        //return SingleTrendCell
    }else{
        //return DoubleTrendCellCell
    }
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    if indexPath.item % 3 == 0{
        //return SingleTrendCell Size
    }
    //return DoubleTrendCellCell Size

}
```

Comment: It didn't solve the problem, the cell are still displayed like the second image above, except that every third index uses the SingleTrendCell

Comment: @SimpiMind If `indexPath.item % 3 == 0{` you need to return single cell not double cell check my answer once again

Comment: Thanks, you've save a life.

Answer (score 2):

Since both your cells have the same structure, there is not point in creating two different kinds of cells. All you have to do is use the `sizeForItemAtIndexPath` method and return appropriate sizes, `autoLayout` will take care of the content inside. Something like:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    if indexPath.item % 3 == 0{

        return CGSize(width: collectionView.bounds.size.width/2.0, height: collectionView.bounds.size.height/3.0)

    }else{

        return CGSize(width: collectionView.bounds.size.width, height: collectionView.bounds.size.height/3.0)
    }
}
```

**Note:** Ensure all your insets and inter item spacings are 0.

Comment: Thanks, i removed the second one